# Pushing git repo to digitalocean ubuntu 12 server

Tags: git, github

I'm having no luck pushing my application files to my digital ocean server. I can successfully push master to the server but it goes into the wrong folder. All files are in `var/www` folder but it should be `var/www/html` I don't know what to change to make sure the files get committed to `html`.

Here's what I have in terminal:

[image: terminal]

and local terminal I have:

```
git remote add final ssh://jmccommas@104.131.73.151/var/www/repos/meanproject.git
git push final master
```

What am I doing wrong that files are not going to the `/var/www/html` directory?

Comment: maybe the issue is in the post-receive file as I have this: #!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www git checkout -f

Comment: should it be: #!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/html git checkout -f   ???

Comment: if you clone the repo somwhere else with just "git clone <path>", what is the directory hierarchy? is this a pulling or pushing problem? I don't understand what you mean by "they are not going into /var/www/html", that's a pull activity not push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it was the post-receive file that had wrong path. It should be:

```
#!/bin/sh GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/html git checkout -f
```

not

```
#!/bin/sh GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www git checkout -f
```

Dumb mistake is all!!

Answer (score 1):

What's the dir structure in your repository meanproject.git?

If your git repo does not have a html top level dir, then create it and clone the files out into that:

```
cd /var/www
mkdir html
cd html
git clone <path to repo>
```

This assumes your files in the repo are:

```
index.html
some-dir/
some-dir/your-image.gif
```

and not

```
html/index.html
html/some-dir/
html/some-dir/your-image.gif
```

**EDIT:** ok, see you found your own solution.